# WebClient from Asp.net gives "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am trying to post to our asterisk box to parse out the phone list

from a console application this works :

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine( HttpPost());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    public static string HttpPost()
    {
        var URI = @"http://sip.ligmarine.com/admin/config.php?quietmode=on&type=tool&display=printextensions";
        var Parameters = "display=printextensions&quietmode=on&type=tool&core=core&featurecodeadmin=featurecodeadmin&paging=paging";
        var retVal = "";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("maint:password")));
        wc.Headers.Add("referer", @"http://sip.ligmarine.com/admin/config.php?type=tool&display=printextensions");
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        retVal = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("maint:password"));
        //Console.Write("Resulting Request Headers: ");
        //Console.WriteLine(wc.Headers.ToString());
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        //Console.WriteLine("Uploading to {0} ...", URI);
        // Upload the input string using the HTTP 1.0 POST method.
        byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadData(URI, "POST", byteArray);
       // Console.WriteLine("\nResponse received was {0}", );

        retVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

from our IIS6 Hosted ASP.NET page I get

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
   where it originated in the code.

```
 Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was      forcibly closed by the remote host

 Source Error:

 Line 37:         //Console.WriteLine("Uploading to {0} ...", URI);
 Line 38:         // Upload the input string using the HTTP 1.0 POST method.
 Line 39:         byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadData(URI, "POST", byteArray);
 Line 40:         // Console.WriteLine("\nResponse received was {0}", );
 Line 41:
```

The HttpPost Method is exactly Identical  the page load :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var ret = HttpPost();
    Response.Write(ret);
}
```

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading?

Comment: no file... using upload data to post form data

Comment: do you have any firewall configured on iis server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a dns issue ... the server was resolving to the private ip  console app was resolving to public

Answer (score 32):

I had very similar situation but different solution. On my Windows 10 dev machine+console app, the `WebClient.UploadData` to a `https` address was working just fine. But when same exact function was copied to a ASP.NET MVC app, and published to different web server (Windows 2008 R2) it was giving this exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send . ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection  was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection  was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

Both projects were using .NET framework 4.6.1

Solved by making the call use `TLS1.2`. Add this just before `UploadData`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

[Source](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/)

Comment: Nice, but do you have a workaround for previous .NET Framework version (i.e : 3.5, where the only SecurityProtocolType available is Tls/Ssl3) ?

Comment: @joym8 Was your issue intermittent? In my case I am facing similar issue on Prod server but issue is intermittent.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, you saved my day.
Requests to an Azure AppService app was throwing the ".. connection was closed" exception.

Setting ***SecurityProtocolType.Tls12*** fixed the problem.

Also works with

```
_webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

and

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
var resp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Setting the security protocol to TLS1.2 did not fix my problem. I had to add another line of code as suggested [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686407/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection).

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Framework 4.0, it only has `Tls` and `Ssl3`,

```
namespace System.Net
{
    public enum SecurityProtocolType
    {
        Ssl3 = 48,
        Tls = 192,
    }
}
```

You can do this at .NET Framework 4.0 to make it work:

```
// ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

for that the `Tls12`'s code is 3072.

Or just upgrade you project, then you can do the commented thing.