# Why is TLS relevant in non-secure http?

Tags: c#, http, https, tls1.2

I am using `WebClient` to get data from a web resource thus:

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
var stream = wc.OpenRead("http://...");
// etc..
```

It used to work until recently, when the server would forcibly close the connection.

Based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45359280), I added the `ServicePointManager` setting thus:

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var stream = wc.OpenRead("http://...");
// etc..
```

… and it once again works as it did before.

I get that TLS is relevant to HTTPS and the effect of the setting is to include TLS1.2 in the handshake, and that the host site must have been recently updated to reject the older vulnerable protocol, but ***why is it necessary for ordinary, non-secure HTTP***?

Comment: I have no idea if `WebClient` can do this or not, but is there a chance it's upgrading the request from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: Based on the code, it is not clear if `WebClient` switches to HTTPS or not. You should be able to use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the packets. If the actual packets go through HTTPS, not HTTP, then clearly the cause is there.

Comment: There are plenty of “301 https://...” responses around. And web client will follow redirects by default

Comment: As far as I know TLS which is the upgrade to the old SSL works with secure protocols like `HTTPS`. There might be a redirection in that web page which is secured.

Answer (score 1):

**[AllowAutoRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect?view=netframework-4.8)** is set to **true** by default in WebClient instances.
Therefore, the request automatically follows redirection responses from your server.

Simply set **AllowAutoRedirect** to false and you will not follow any redirection, so you will not have to deal with SSL/TLS handshakes.

Of course, if your server does not want to serve your request with HTTP, you will not get the content you are looking for. Anyway, setting **AllowAutoRedirect** to false will help you confirm that the behaviour you encounter is due to a redirect.